# Jackson custom deserializer for abstract class

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, abstract-class

I have an object that is sent to the server via JSON from the client. The object itself has multiple attributes that are complex datatypes themselves. Most of them can be serialized just fine by the standard Jackson deserializer.

Hovewer some of the attributes belong to different subclasses of an abstract super-class, which themselves have attributes that are subclasses of a different abstract super-class.

The problem with that is that I dont have the information of which class the object belongs to in the `@JacksonDeserializer` class.

The hierarchy can be seen like this:

```
public class PetOwner extends Person {

    public String name;
    public ArrayList<Pet> pets;
}

public class CatOwner extends Person {

    public String name;
    public Cat cat;
}

public class Cat extends Pet {

    public String name;
    public String color;
}
//Both Person and Pet are abstract classes
```

These are just example classes to illustrate the problem.
I would need the Deserializer to do the following:
For all instances of CatOwner the cat can be deserialized directly since it's an instance of a non-abstact class. For all instances of PetOwner his pets need to be deserialized without knowing the sub-class they belong to (=which type of Pet they are).

Now the question is, can I tell the `@JacksonDeserializer` class to only be called if I don't have the information about which type of `Pet` has to be deserialized ?

I tried it the following way:
In the `@JacksonDeserializer` class for `Pet` I create one random type of pet, give it an `ID` and later convert it in a Service to the correct type of `Pet` via looking up the ID. 
This works for the case where the Owner is a `PetOwner`. But if the Owner is a `CatOwner` it can obviously not just set the `cat` attribute to e.g. a `Dog` object. So I would like the `@JacksonDeserializer`to only be called if the owner is a `PetOwner`